# How to get the keys of Azure Bing Maps API for Enterprise using Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, api, bing-maps, bing-api

I have seen that two keys generated for an Azure Bing Maps API. I want to retrieve those two keys using Powershell. Do we have any commands to get this to be done.

Comment: You created your keys and you want to read it by your Powershell ?

Comment: I have created Bing Map API in azure portal and there are two keys generated for Bing Maps API. I need to fetch those keys by using powershell. I have not created any keys in it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to do that with the Bing Maps accounts via Azure Marketplace. Since you are using Azure, you might want to take a look at Azure Maps. It is a native Azure service and supports ARM templates and all the other standard Azure admin type services.

https://azure.com/maps

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/

https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/index.html